# modifying main event handler

Tags: java, android, macos

Is there a main handler for android applications. For example, can i override the main event handler such that when the events come in i can log the events and then pass them to the original main handler to be processed? is there something similar for Java on android?

I know this is possible on Mac OS x its called method swizzling

```
            My_mainHandler(event e){

            //log event e
                                 log(e)

            //send event to main handler to be processed

            maineventhandler(e)

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a main handler for android application?

Kind of. Use [Looper.getMainLooper();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper%28%29) and the create a new Handler passing that looper.

> can i override the main event handler

As far as I know, without getting into the source of Android, you can't. Again, I just recommend capturing the Looper and using that instead. I'm not sure if you will be able to see the events though....

EDIT:

This is for capturing *your* application looper. I don't think you can capture the OS's looper.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you say caputure the Looper and use that instead, i dont really understand what your trying to say. Can you please edit the answer and include sample code ? thanks!